# How to run database query from module context

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I want to send a `database query` from the `context module`.

The reason I want to do this is to be able to render a page without showing the actual raw data to the end-user.

When I use `node-fetch` or `SvelteKit Fetch` the JSON data gets to shown to the end-user.

`node-fetch` makes `fetch request` and `JSON` gets exposed through that `API` call.

`Sveltekit Fetch` doesn't make additional `API` calls but inserts the raw data to the actual rendered `HTML` page.

So I think that's better to send a `query` from `context module`.
How can I make a `database` call from `context module`?

This is my code:

```
<script context="module">

    import pool from '$lib/db.js';

    export async function load() {
        
        const objects = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM items')

        return {
            props: { objects }
        }
    }

</script>
```

The error:

```
500
The requested module '/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js' does not provide an export named 'Pool'
SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js' does not provide an export named 'Pool'
```

Inside `db.js`:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const pool = new Pool({
    user: "testuser",
    password: "1234567",
    database: "test",
    host: "localhost",
    port: "5432"
});

export default pool;
```

Comment: Will this query be viewable from Inspect tab?

Answer (score 0):

`node-postgres` `pg` library that you are trying to import is *transpiled*. This means that you can't use named imports the way you are here.

Try changing:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
```

with:

```
import * as pg from 'pg';
const { Pool } = pg;
```

Comment: Yes, I did that but it didn't solve the problem